# Skip count "starting at one"

Tags: education

My daughter is taking a second grade math class and they are learning to "skip count" I am guessing this means to count by [n]. The directions say "Start at 1. Skip count by 2." and the worksheet has a 10x10 grid where they are supposed to color in the numbers.

Maybe my comprehension skills are failing, and I'm probably over thinking this, but we both find "Start at 1" confusing. Do you think they mean (3,5,7...) or is this standard count by 2 (e.g. 2,4,6...)?

Who said there are no dumb questions?

Comment: They probably mean $1,3,5,7\dots$.

Comment: "Skip count" means to count while skipping, or to skip while counting.  Both are more fun when done together than when done separately.

Comment: Was the class given similar problems?  Were they asked, say, to start at 1 and skip count by 3, or to start at 2 and skip count by 2?

Comment: @Joel :( The worksheets have no other instruction. Literally. "Start at 1. Skip count by 2." My kids "stay on green" and pay attention in class... and possibly forget what they were taught before they get home? But they say the teacher didn't explain it. I struggle with these problems everyday. They taught it a little different 20 years ago. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably mean $1,3,5,7,\dots$.  After all, if we said "start at $1$ and count to $5$," we would respond $1,2,3,4,5$. There is some ambiguity, of course, but I imagine that in a classroom setting a sample was provided. And it is not a dumb question.

Comment: Logical answer. Thank you.